# Series inductance increasing piezo volume

Tags: inductor, piezo

Does an inductor in series with a piezo *element* increase its volume?  If so, is it because of collapsing magnetic fields?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so but maybe you have evidence that it does. If so then more detail is required.

Comment: @Andyaka it seemed to. Then my gameboys sound broke :(

Answer (score 2):

The only way to increase the power transfer to a transducer of any sort is to reduce the impedance it presents to the source.

A piezo transducer is primarily a capacitive load, so it's conceivable that adding an inductance could partially cancel its capacitive reactance by (at least partially) resonating with it at the frequency of interest, increasing the voltage across the piezo relative to the source voltage.

The specific value of inductance required to do this would depend on the frequency(s) involved and the physical characteristics of the particular transducer.

Comment: Dave tweed is correct .I looked at this for an ultrasonic piezo transducer and got more voltage swing than would have otherwise been available on a 12V battery and half bridge .This meant that a fixed inductor was used which was and still is cheaper than a transformer .

Comment: Considering piezos are mainly capacitive, wouldn't a resistor be better? A parallel rc circuit

Comment: @AlexanderM: Better at what? A resistor can only dissipate energy; it cannot store energy or resonate with a capacitor.